# OpenShift redhead nodeJs project changes do not take effect in the app

Tags: node.js, git, build, openshift

I am using openshift redhat (https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift) for hosting a simple nodeJs application. (web hosting, I do not have redhat running locally)

I have an application, and the sources are from the existing git repository.

(so, I chose the **import from git** option, when creation an app in the openshift web interface)

Upon creation of the application and initial build, all works well, including the page (using the **open url** option).

#### The problem

When I add, commit and push code changes to the git repo and rebuild the application, the web application does not contain the code changes.

- I add, commit and push to the git
- in buildconfigs, I click on **start build** option, as shown in the following illustration:
  [image]

  - note: if I would go to **builds** and select **rebuild**, I found out that it just runs the same build again, without adding the git repo changes (as shown in the illustration below), so I do not do it this way
    [image]
- I click on **open url** to navigate to the built project, and I see the **old code** in the web html, without the recent code changes I made and pushed to the git repository
- I also launched a **workspace** of the application, to view the code which is present on the openshift, and I do see the code changes I want in the source code files (as displayed in illustration below)

[image]

- however, these changes are not visible on the opened web URL

  - I also tried **ctrl + R** to flush the web cache

What is the reason for this? How do I refresh the application to see the changes, do I have to restart it somehow?

The way around it is to create a new application in openshift from repo, and then I see the changes, but it is quite ugly way to do this every time code changes in deployment.

It seems that maybe the running application shall be restarted somehow? As perhaps the previous build is still running? However, due to seeing physically the code changes in the **workspace**, I think the reason for this problem is not that the would always run from the cache, or local files. Moreover, in the build console I always see message **Cloning "https://gitlab.com/glaseja1/test.git"**

I searched for this problem and did not find an answer.
I would like to, if possible, avoid using dockerfiles and build files, as it is too complicated. I simply have project with working .js files and package.json file in the following public repository: *https://gitlab.com/glaseja1/test*